# VML Background code breaks aligns Outlook E-Mail tables

Tags: background, html-table, alignment, html-email, vml

I'm using VML code to show background in an HTML mail. I have 3 tables in a single table cell and they are standing right next to each other, but when I test my e-mail in Outlook tables are no longer next to each other and it aligns my three tables vertically like every table is in a line.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
    align="center" class="normal" style=
    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <tr>
                         <td background="http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" style="background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png');" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="600" height="700" valign="top">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect strokecolor='none' style='width:600px;height:700px;'>
    <v:fill color='#363636' src='http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png' type='tile'></v:fill>
  </v:rect>
  <v:shape id='NameHere' style='position:absolute;width:600px;height:700px;'></v:shape>
<![endif]-->
  <div><table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0"
          cellspacing="0" align="center" class=
          "spaced2" >
                              <tr>
                                <td valign="top" style="border:none;"><table class="aligntable" border="0" cellpadding=
                "0" cellspacing="0" align="left"
                style=
                "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;"><tr>
                                  <td height="20">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" align="center"><img border="0" src=
                      "" width="180" height="180" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" valign="middle" align="center"
                     style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #0b5ed7;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;padding: 0;margin: 0;text-align: left;line-height: 150%;letter-spacing: 0px;">
                                        <center>
                                      TEST
                                        </center></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" height="255" valign="top"
                    align="left" style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #000000;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;outline: none;line-height: 120%;">TEST </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" valign="top" width="180"><img src=
                      ""
                      border="0" 
                      /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                  <table width="20" align="left" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                  <table class="aligntable2" border="0" cellpadding=
                "0" cellspacing="0" align="left"
                style=
                "display:block; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;"><tr><td height="20"></td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" align="center"> <img border="0" src=
                      "" width="180" height="180" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" valign="middle" align="center"
                     style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #0b5ed7;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;padding: 0;margin: 0;text-align: left;line-height: 150%;letter-spacing: 0px;">
                                        <center>
                                          TEST
                                        </center></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" height="255" valign="top"
                    align="left" style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #000000;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;outline: none;line-height: 120%;"> TEST</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" width="180"><a target="_blank" style=
                      "FONT-SIZE: 16px; COLOR: #0e5fd8; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial; text-decoration:none; line-height:16px;"
                      href=
                      "http://www.philips.at/c-p/NTRX100_12/?origin=3_at_de_spoilyourself2__ot_dec__hero_img&elqtrack=true"> <img src=
                      ""
                      border="0"  /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                  <table class="aligntable3" border="0" cellpadding=
                "0" cellspacing="0" align="right"
                style=
                "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;"><tr><td height="20"></td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" align="center"><img border="0" src=
                      "" width="180" height="180" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" valign="middle" align="center"
                     style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #0b5ed7;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;padding: 0;margin: 0;text-align: left;line-height: 150%;letter-spacing: 0px;">
                                        <center>
                                          TEST
                                        </center></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" height="255" valign="top"
                    align="left" style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #000000;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;outline: none;line-height: 120%;">TEST </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" width="180"> <img src=
                      "" alt=
                     width="50"
                      border="0"/></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--END TD -->
                              </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>






                        </tr>
                      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I just ran into this issue as well and figured out a fix.

What's happening here is that after the `</table>` and before the `<table>`, Outlook VML adds a Word paragraph marker which forces the tables to display stacked rather than inline with each other.

Between the `</table><table>` put this piece of conditional code

```
<!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
```

Your code would look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
    align="center" class="normal" style=
    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <tr>
                         <td background="http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" style="background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png');" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="600" height="700" valign="top">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect strokecolor='none' style='width:600px;height:700px;'>
    <v:fill color='#363636' src='http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png' type='tile'></v:fill>
  </v:rect>
  <v:shape id='NameHere' style='position:absolute;width:600px;height:700px;'></v:shape>
<![endif]-->
  <div><table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0"
          cellspacing="0" align="center" class=
          "spaced2" >
                              <tr>
                                <td valign="top" style="border:none;"><table class="aligntable" border="0" cellpadding=
                "0" cellspacing="0" align="left"
                style=
                "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;"><tr>
                                  <td height="20">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" align="center"><img border="0" src=
                      "" width="180" height="180" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" valign="middle" align="center"
                     style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #0b5ed7;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;padding: 0;margin: 0;text-align: left;line-height: 150%;letter-spacing: 0px;">
                                        <center>
                                      TEST
                                        </center></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" height="255" valign="top"
                    align="left" style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #000000;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;outline: none;line-height: 120%;">TEST </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" valign="top" width="180"><img src=
                      ""
                      border="0" 
                      /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                  <table width="20" align="left" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                  <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
                                  <table class="aligntable2" border="0" cellpadding=
                "0" cellspacing="0" align="left"
                style=
                "display:block; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;"><tr><td height="20"></td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" align="center"> <img border="0" src=
                      "" width="180" height="180" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" valign="middle" align="center"
                     style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #0b5ed7;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;padding: 0;margin: 0;text-align: left;line-height: 150%;letter-spacing: 0px;">
                                        <center>
                                          TEST
                                        </center></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" height="255" valign="top"
                    align="left" style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #000000;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;outline: none;line-height: 120%;"> TEST</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" width="180"><a target="_blank" style=
                      "FONT-SIZE: 16px; COLOR: #0e5fd8; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial; text-decoration:none; line-height:16px;"
                      href=
                      "http://www.philips.at/c-p/NTRX100_12/?origin=3_at_de_spoilyourself2__ot_dec__hero_img&elqtrack=true"> <img src=
                      ""
                      border="0"  /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                  <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
                                  <table class="aligntable3" border="0" cellpadding=
                "0" cellspacing="0" align="right"
                style=
                "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;"><tr><td height="20"></td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" align="center"><img border="0" src=
                      "" width="180" height="180" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" valign="middle" align="center"
                     style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #0b5ed7;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;padding: 0;margin: 0;text-align: left;line-height: 150%;letter-spacing: 0px;">
                                        <center>
                                          TEST
                                        </center></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="180" height="255" valign="top"
                    align="left" style=
                    "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse;color: #000000;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;outline: none;line-height: 120%;">TEST </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" width="180"> <img src=
                      "" alt=
                     width="50"
                      border="0"/></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="20" width="180"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--END TD -->
                              </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>






                        </tr>
                      </table>
</body>
</html>
```